# PHP Calculate Number of downline in binary tree

Tags: php, mysql

For calculating numbers of downline in binary tree, I am trying the following script by making 2 databases for registration and members downline structure. It works actually.

But the members structure database grow very fast. Caused n level in binary tree will generate n records for single user registration. I am just wondering if user register at level 1000 then it will create 1000 record in single user registration.

Any other solution for this system?

The full long script is :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `member` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(55) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `upline` varchar(55) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `position` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `sponsor` varchar(55) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `_left` varchar(55) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `_right` varchar(55) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

make table of downline structure :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `net_downline` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `upline` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `position` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

As get from simple or basic registration form :

```
$newuser        = htmlentities(trim($_POST['user']));
$sponsor        = htmlentities(trim($_POST['sponsor']));    
$upline         = htmlentities(trim($_POST['upline']));
$position       = htmlentities(trim($_POST['position']));
```

During registration process, this tree steps is executed :

```
// 1. register new member
$users->dummyRegister($newuser, $sponsor, $upline, $position);
// 2. update upline
$users->dummyUpdateUpline($newuser, $upline, $position);

// 3. create donwline structure of binary tree
$level=0;
$memberid=$newuser;
do{
$getdata=$users->dummyGetUpline($memberid); 
$uplne=$getdata[2]; 
$posi=$getdata[3];

$level++;
if($uplne!==''){
$users->dummyInsert_NetDownline($newuser, $uplne, $posi, $level);
}
$memberid=$uplne;
}
while($memberid!='');
```

class "user" for that script :

```
<?php  // start class

    class Users{

        private $db;
        public function __construct($database) {
            $this->db = $database;
        }   
    public function dummyRegister($username, $sponsor, $upline, $position, $today){

            $query  = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `member` (`username`, `sponsor`, `upline`, `position`, `entry_date` ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");          
            $query->bindValue(1, $username);
            $query->bindValue(2, $sponsor);
            $query->bindValue(3, $upline);
            $query->bindValue(4, $position);
            $query->bindValue(5, $today);

            try{
                $query->execute();
             }catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }   
        }


    public function dummyUpdateUpline($username, $upline, $position){

            if ($position=='left') {
            $query  = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `member` SET `_left`=? WHERE username=? ");
            }elseif ($position=='right') {
            $query  = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `member` SET `_right`=? WHERE username=? ");
            }

            $query->bindValue(1, $username);
            $query->bindValue(2, $upline);

            try{
                $query->execute();

            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }   
        }

    public function dummyGetUpline($newuser) {// for demo

            $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `member` WHERE `username`= ?");
            $query->bindValue(1, $newuser);

            try{
                $query->execute();
                $rows = $query->fetch();

                return $rows;//['upline'];

            } catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

    public function dummyInsert_NetDownline($newuser, $upline, $posi, $level){// for demo

            $query  = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `net_downline` (`username`, `upline`, `position`, `level` ) VALUES (?, ?, ? ,?) ");
            $query->bindValue(1, $newuser);
            $query->bindValue(2, $upline);
            $query->bindValue(3, $posi);
            $query->bindValue(4, $level);

            try{
                $query->execute();

            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }   
        }   

    }// endclass
```

create initial.php and put on top regitration php script :

```
<?php  
if(!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }
require 'conn/database.php'; // in folder conn
require 'clas/users.php';   // in folder class
$users      = new Users($db);
} 
?>
```

this to handle database connection (clas/database.php script) :

```
<?php 
$config = array(
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'dbname'    => 'sampledatabase'
);

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['dbname'], $config['username'], $config['password']);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Dealing with trees in relation-DB isn't such simple as in application. In common sense, adjanced-tree is a design-antipattern

Comment: I'd suggest you use [nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) for this. With NS, calculating a path to a node will be as simple as `SELECT x WHERE x.left < node.left AND x.right > node.right`.

Comment: georg, could you please write the sample script as NS is used?

Comment: @user3706926: Ah, you're using it already, right?. So, what's the problem exactly?

Comment: I get the problem of database file for member structure. The size is growing bigger and bigger. I think that is not normal georg. Difficult in handling for large users.

Comment: @user3706926: What I don't understand is why you need the "downline" table in the first place. You can always retrieve this data dynamically from the NS model. (Also, if you want someone to read your comments, use the `@` sign before the username).

Comment: @georg: Could you give me a link or example of using NS?

Comment: Finally, I get my own conclusion how to calculate downlines and show member tree in php. Just simple calculation without NS. Just using single member table with no member structure table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer after I try many ways. Solving my previous problem. Just using a single member table above.

To show number of downlines, left and right. I insert this script in the HTML member tree page for every user in the tree A, down to B/C, down to D/E/F/G ):

```
<?php echo $users->downline_number($member,'_left'); ?>
<?php echo $users->downline_number($member,'_right'); ?>
```

Add this function in User Class ;

```
function downline_number($member,$position) {

$query  = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `member` WHERE `upline`='$member' AND `position`='$position'");
        $query->bindValue(1, $member);
        $query->bindValue(2, $position);

try{
        $query->execute();
        $rows = $query->fetch();

        if($this->count_downline($member,$position) >0 ){
        $total=$this->total_members_down($rows['username']);
        }else{
        $total=0;
        }

        return $total;      

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }   

    }   

function count_downline($member,$position) {

$query  = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `member` WHERE `upline`=? AND `position`=? ");
        $query->bindValue(1, $member);
        $query->bindValue(2, $position);
    try{
        $query->execute();
        return $rows = $query->rowCount();

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }   
    }   

function total_members_down($upline,$reset=0) {
global $num;
if ($reset==0) { $num=1; }

$query  = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `member` where `upline`='$upline' order by id asc");
        $query->bindValue(1, $upline);
try{

$query->execute();

if ($upline !='') {

            if ($this->total_down($upline) > 0 ) {
                    while ($rows = $query->fetch() ) {
                    $num++;
                    $this->total_members_down($rows['username'],$num);
                    } 
                    return $num;
            } else { 
            return $num;
            }
} else { $num=0; return $num;  }            

     }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }   
}   

function total_down($upline) {

$query  = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `member` where `upline`='$upline' order by id asc ");
        $query->bindValue(1, $upline);

    try{
        $query->execute();
        return $rows = $query->rowCount();

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }   
    }
```

and it works showing binary member tree structure. Showing the memberID is not attached here, caused it simple way. Just left & right downlines number.

Hope this post will help others who need it. Any suggestion for better ways?