# Get last Left Child in binary tree in php

Tags: php, mysql, binary-tree, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

i am trying to get the last left child of sponsor id in a Binary tree.
Like: this is present situation(in picture), when id7 whats to add a customer(whose id will be 14) in his left side then it will join under id10(which is known upline of id14). because its the last left children of id7.

I tried lot of examples like:[PHP Calculate Number of downline in binary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323039/php-calculate-number-of-downline-in-binary-tree)

, but didn't find useful
[image]

So, how can i find the last left node of sponsor id 7. which is used when inserting a new Customer.

Here is my database:--- "cm-customers"

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This needs some PHP code for context. Also why binary trees inside a database? That's not something you usually see.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.0, you can do this with a recursive query:

```
with recursive nodes as (
    select serial_id, upline, left pos, 1 lvl from customers where upline = 0
    union all
    select c.serial_id, c.upline, n.left + c.left, n.lvl + 1
    from nodes n
    inner join customers c on c.upline = n.serial_id
)
select *
from nodes
order by lvl desc, pos desc
limit 1
```

The query traverse the hierarchy tree from the root to the leafs, while keeping track of the level of each node and of how many "left" nodes were visited. You can then use this information to identify the deepest, most left node.

Comment: @Anmolsingh: no, this requires MySQL 8.0. A task such as walking a hierarchy will be much more challenging to perform in earlier versions of MySQL, where recursive queries are not available.